# check size of copied file by batch file

Tags: batch-file, plsql, oracle11g, windows-10

a friend of mine wrote a batch script a few years back. it was working fine but suddenly after a migration, it is not working fine. we used this piece of code in oracle form.This pieces of code, copy some file from source to destination and then check the size of all files is equal in source and destination then let you delete the files.

can you check and keep me posted why I am receiving this error and how I can solve it??

This code generate the next batch script and it is written in Oracle form(PL/SQL):

```
lv_content0 := 'NET USE Z: '||lv_folder;

lv_content1:= 'md '||lv_path; --- what is the content of .bat
lv_content2:= 'start "" "'||lv_path||'"';
--lv_content3:= 'FOR /D %%I in ('|| :CMMT_FIX_MASTER.V_FIX_LOC ||'\*.*) DO move %%I '||lv_path;
lv_content3:= 'XCOPY /H /D /Y /S /E /V /F '|| :CMMT_FIX_MASTER.V_FIX_LOC ||'\*.* '||lv_path;

--13062012 add exception to move folder to patches folder --------
lv_content4a:=  '@For /F "tokens=*" %%a IN (' || '''"dir /s /-c "' || :CMMT_FIX_MASTER.V_FIX_LOC || '" | find "bytes" | find /v "free""''' || ') do @Set summaryout1=%%a'; 
lv_content4b:=  '@For /f "tokens=1,2 delims=)" %%a in ("%summaryout1%") do @set filesout1=%%a&set sizeout1=%%b'; 
lv_content4c:=  '@Set sizeout1=%sizeout1:bytes=%' ;
lv_content4d:=  '@Set sizeout1=%sizeout1: =%';

lv_content5a:=  '@For /F "tokens=*" %%a IN ('|| '''"dir /s /-c "' || lv_path || '" | find "bytes" | find /v "free""''' || ') do @Set summaryout2=%%a';
lv_content5b:=  '@For /f "tokens=1,2 delims=)" %%a in ("%summaryout2%") do @set filesout2=%%a&set sizeout2=%%b';
lv_content5c:=  '@Set sizeout2=%sizeout2:bytes=%';
lv_content5d:=  '@Set sizeout2=%sizeout2: =%';

lv_content6:= '@if %sizeout1% == %sizeout2%' || '  ' || 'RD /S  ' || :CMMT_FIX_MASTER.V_FIX_LOC ;
lv_content7:= '@if not %sizeout1% == %sizeout2%' || '  ' || 'echo Folders are not completely sync..Please check !! ' ;  
lv_content8:= '@if not %sizeout1% == %sizeout2%' || '  ' || 'pause' ;
```

This is result:

```
NET USE Z: \\ABC\
md \\XXXX\2018\2018-01\10012018\
start "" "\\XXXX\2018\2018-01\10012018\"
XCOPY /H /D /Y /S /E /V /F P:\AAAA\19070\*.* \\XXXX\2018\2018-01\10012018\

@For /F "tokens=*" %%a IN ('"dir /s /-c "P:\AAAA\19070" | find "bytes" | find /v "free""') do @Set summaryout1=%%a
@For /f "tokens=1,2 delims=)" %%a in ("nullummaryout1%") do @set filesout1=%%a&set sizeout1=%%b
@Set sizeout1=nullizeout1:bytes=%
@Set sizeout1=nullizeout1: =%

@For /F "tokens=*" %%a IN ('"dir /s /-c "\\XXXX\2018\2018-01\10012018\" | find "bytes" | find /v "free""') do @Set summaryout2=%%a
@For /f "tokens=1,2 delims=)" %%a in ("nullummaryout2%") do @set filesout2=%%a&set sizeout2=%%b
@Set sizeout2=nullizeout2:bytes=%
@Set sizeout2=nullizeout2: =%
@if nullizeout1% == nullizeout2%  RD /S  P:\AAAA\19070
@if not nullizeout1% == nullizeout2%  echo Folders are not completely sync..Please check !! 
@if not nullizeout1% == nullizeout2%  pause

EXIT;
```

error:

```
2 File(s) copied
The system cannot find the file nullummaryout1b @Set sizeout1 nullizeout1:bytes @Set sizeout1 nullizeout1: @For /F "tokens=*" %a IN ('"dir /s /-c "\\XXXX\2018\2018-01\10012018\" | find "bytes" | find /v "free""'.
```

Comment: Please review [MCVE].  A list of file names in the source directory and the names of any files that made it to the destination directory might help.

Comment: What parameters did you call the script with?

Comment: @jwdonahue: shorter than this was not possible. I edited my question. can you check it again, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to using PUTF instead of PUT happen. please refer to this question for more information:
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48199635/convert-s-to-null-in-plsql/48202275#48202275)

Answer (score 1):

The code is very clumsy, but that's simply a matter of æsthestics.

This code:

```
@Set sizeout1=nullizeout1:bytes=%
@Set sizeout1=nullizeout1: =%
```

makes no logical sense.

And this:

```
@if not nullizeout1% == nullizeout2%  echo Folders are not completely sync..Please check !! 
@if not nullizeout1% == nullizeout2%  pause
```

equally would generate a syntax error.

Please compare the original code with this "migrated" version.

Now - suppose `%s` in the original has been replaced by `null` in the migrated version. The original would then be a much more sensible

```
@Set sizeout1=%sizeout1:bytes=%
@Set sizeout1=%sizeout1: =%

@if not %sizeout1% == %sizeout2%  echo Folders are not completely sync..Please check !! 
@if not %sizeout1% == %sizeout2%  pause
```

still clumsy, but now valid and actually doing something.

So I conclude that your problem is that your migration mechanism has converted `%s` to `null` for some reason.

From there, the fix is is your court.

I'm not familiar with Oracle forms, but if you are dynamically generating the batch, then you need to find a way to escape the processing that is causing `%s` to be replaced by the current value of `s` (and `s` is not defined, hence it's being replaced by `null`). I don't know what the escape-character is, or whether as a quick-and-dirty solution you could set the value of `s` to the literal `%s`.

If this is simply a batch file to be run and doesn't change, then replace every string `null` to `%s` using a text-editor and save the result, then run the batch by name rather than by regenerating it from Oracle.

Comment: I check the code, it seems that they are similar but I am not sure why %s converted to null. I modify my question, can you check the actual code, please?