# convert %S to null in plsql

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, oracle12c, oracleforms

I observe a problem after migrating my oracle form 6i to 11g. In a form I am generating windows batch command. part of the command is as below:

```
declare
    lv_content5c varchar2(300);
begin
    lv_content5c:=  '@Set sizeout2=%sizeout2:bytes=%';
    CLIENT_TEXT_IO.PUTF(out_file,lv_content5c);
    CLIENT_TEXT_IO.PUTF(out_file, CHR(10));     
    CLIENT_TEXT_IO.FCLOSE(out_file);
    client_host('cmd /c  start '|| lv_filename);
end;
```

it seems that when I store this text "'@Set sizeout2=%sizeout2:bytes=%'" in file oracleForm or Plsql convert it as below:

> @Set sizeout2=nullizeout2:bytes=%

as it can be observe %s  converted to null in output file. would you mind advising me what is the issue and have you ever face similar issue?

Please take note that my backend is 12c and frontend is 11gR2.

Comment: To what `%s` are you referring? You are aware that proper cmd scripts have CR/LF line terminators yes?  Just the LF will definitely yield a broken script file.  Also any UNICODE byte order marks (BOM's) at the start of the file, will break the script, make sure you are writing ANSI or UTF-8 no BOM.

Comment: Have you tried using `PUT` instead of `PUTF`?

Comment: You should show the **relevant** batch code, where the psql text shall be expanded

Comment: @jwdonahue: thanks for the tip.

Comment: @pablomatico: thanks you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PUTF takes the first string argument to be a format specification, with subsequent strings being the content. Also, you need a proper line terminator. So do PUT_LINE(out_file,lv_content5c); and delete the following line (the one with `CHR(10)`).